# Adding changes from another commit except for some files

Tags: git, github

I have broken my commit by adding too many files, so I reverted back to the previous commit, created new branch out of it, and now I have a new branch with old commit on it.

I want to add all changes from the commit after reverting except for the redundant files.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to revert, just do `git rm` on the files you didn't want, then do `git commit --amend` to alter the bad commit so it doesn't include those files.

Alternatively, do a `git cherry-pick -n <bad-commit-id>` to apply the bad commit to the current branch, then edit it by removing the unwanted parts, then commit.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which might come in handy if you're trying to undo commits for not only added files, but also fixes deleted or changes to files is to soft reset the commit and unstage the changes.

```
git reset --soft HEAD~
git reset -- PathToFileNotWantedInCommit
git commit -c ORIG_HEAD
```